# ¿Cómo puedo meter varios archivos .txt ingresados por el usuario y meter esos archivos en un archivo .dat?

Tags: c++

Este es mi código, realiza búsquedas de versículos bíblicos que se encuentran en un `.txt`; tengo varios de estos archivos que son libros de la biblia, y me gustaría meter esos archivos a un `.dat` y así mismo si el usuario desea ingresar un libro de texto a la hora de ingresarlo sera por `.txt` y que se convierta a `.dat`. La idea es tener como una base de datos en un `.dat` y desde ahí poder buscar libros y versículos de la biblia.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    system("color f1");
        system("@mode 90,80");
    char linea[1024], buscar[55], FileName[50];
    int Cap=0,Capitulo=0, Ver=0, Versiculo;
    cout << "Nombre del libro: "; cin >> FileName;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Capitulo: "; cin >> Capitulo;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Versiculo: "; cin >> Versiculo;
    cout << endl;
    FILE *fich;
    fich = fopen(FileName, "rb");
    while(fgets(linea, 1024, (FILE*) fich)) {

        sscanf(linea, "%d:%d", &Cap, &Ver);
        if(Cap==Capitulo && Ver==Versiculo){
            printf("%s", linea);
        }
    }
    fclose(fich);
}
```

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta **concreta** ? Deberías pasarte por [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funciona el sitio. En concreto, repasa [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia hay entre un archivo `dat` y uno `txt`?

Comment: Pues así me lo pidieron, tienen que estar en un dat, me podrías ayudar amigo?

Answer (score 0):

ya probaste el uso de estructuras para facilitar la escritura asi mismo la busqueda?
Podrias hacer uso de una estructura para almacenar los datos y escribirlos con el comando fwrite(&VariableTipoEstructura,sizeof(NombreDeLaEstructura),1,Archivo);

''''
IMPORTANTE:
si vas a leer un char con determinado espacio necesitas utilizar
'cin.getline();' en vez de un 'cin' el cin.getline tiene 3 parametros que son los siguientes:
cin.getline(Variable,Tamaño,Delimitador);
la variable es la tipo char, el tamaño es lo que esta dentro de corchetes , solo debes escribir el numero sin corchetes en el cin.getline, delimitador, ya sea un salto de linea
' '\n' ' o un fin de linea ' '\0' ';
Por cierto tu metodo de apertura esta mal amigo debes colocar:
FILE *Archivo=fopen("nombre.dat","a+b"); a+b para , si el archivo no existe se crea y si ya existe le agrege contenido al final. :D Feliz Dia

''''